# Calendar in the app doesn't show in Android 5.0, WebView

Tags: android, webview, calendar

There is no error in Android 4.4. But the Calendar view doesn't show in Android 5.0. There is debug message in `Console Window`.

> "Calendar", source: https://Yourweb.com/js/main.js (289)
>   I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to display 'Web-link' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.", source: Web-link (0)

What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the google play services_lib version in Android 5.0 , Calendar owner need to turn Public mode to share his Calendar

[The Google support calendar answer](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082)

[The same problem question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574354/refused-to-display-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-deny-in-android-we)

So if want to show Calendar in Android 5.0 without set up the public, need to reference lower version google play services_lib