# Displaying iCal through Google - Refused to display because X-Frame-Options is set to Deny

Tags: javascript, html, https, icalendar

I'm trying to display an iCal feed on Wix by using Google Calendar. Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574354/refused-to-display-a-frame-because-it-set-x-frame-options-to-deny-in-android-we), I'm running into an error where the calendar will not display because the login page has `X-Frame-Options` set to `Deny`. However, the solution to that question will not work since I'm dealing with an external calendar feed. Are there any other workarounds that allow the calendar to be embedded? Alternatively, are there any changes to the calendar I can request for the host server to make to allow Google to treat it as "public"?

The calender frame:

```html
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23ffffff&amp;ctz=America%2FNew_York&amp;src=c251MHBkbWs2YmhyOXNpZmhscmJzN2pyOTA2YXU5dXNAaW1wb3J0LmNhbGVuZGFyLmdvb2dsZS5jb20&amp;color=%23E67C73&amp;showNav=1" style="border:solid 1px #777" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The error:

```js
Refused to display 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cl&passive=1209600&osid=1&continue=https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height%3D600%26wkst%3D1%26bgcolor%3D%2523ffffff%26ctz%3DAmerica/New_York%26src%3Dc251MHBkbWs2YmhyOXNpZmhscmJzN2pyOTA2YXU5dXNAaW1wb3J0LmNhbGVuZGFyLmdvb2dsZS5jb20%26color%3D%2523E67C73%26showNav%3D1&followup=https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height%3D600%26wkst%3D1%26bgcolor%3D%2523ffffff%26ctz%3DAmerica/New_York%26src%3Dc251MHBkbWs2YmhyOXNpZmhscmJzN2pyOTA2YXU5dXNAaW1wb3J0LmNhbGVuZGFyLmdvb2dsZS5jb20%26color%3D%2523E67C73%26showNav%3D1&scc=1' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that that google calendar is set to 'make available to public" ?   and that you have right embed code?   Can check by using a browser in which you are not logged in to google and using the url to see whether you get bounced to the login screen or ical file loads.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I just missed the "Make the calendar publicly accessible" checkbox when adding the calendar to my Google Account. It seems weird that the permissions can only be set when creating the calendar and not changed later on, but it is a solution nonetheless.